# php problems in search function

Tags: php, search

Im trying to add search function.
i want it to work like that: for exmple if i have 5 field, and user wrote only in 2, the search will be based only on 2 field. I mean it not neccesary to write information in all 5 field, i want search will happen only in filled fields.

And now it works only if i will write something in all fields (for now i have 2). And if i will write only in one field it doesnt show anything.

Code:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="container">
 <h1>Поиск</h1>
 <form action="search_form.php" method="post">
 <p>Направление</p>
 <input type="text" name="course" />
 <p>Форма обучения</p>
 <input type="text" name="form" />
 <input type="submit" value="Искать">
 </form>
 <?php
 $db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die (mysql_error ());
 mysql_select_db("university", $db) or die(mysql_error());
 $w = array('TRUE');
 if (isset($_POST['course']))
    {
    $course = $_POST['course'];
    $w[] = "course='$course'";
    }
 if (isset($_POST['form']))
    {
    $form = $_POST['form'];
    $w[]= "form='$form'";
    }
 $where = implode($w, ' AND '); 
 $query = ('SELECT * FROM news WHERE '.$where);
 $result = mysql_query($query,$db);
 if($result !== false)
    {
      $news = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      while($news = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {?>
      <tr>
      <td><?=$news['id']?></td>
      <td><?=$news['program']?></td>
      </tr><?
      }
      }
 else 
     {
      echo 'Sorry, we didn't find anything.';
      }?>  
</div>            
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ftr: [Don't use `mysql_*` functions!!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) Besides,your code is open to SQL injections…

Comment: Try `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of `mysql_`!

Answer (score 1):

You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Learn about and fix that before you do ANYTHING else with this code.

Plus your logic is faulty: `mysql_query()` returns false on errors. A query which has no results is **NOT** an error, and still returns a valid query handle. It'll simply have 0 rows on it.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ($result === false) {
   die(mysql_error());
} else if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   die("No results");
} else {
   ... display results
}
```

Comment: i changed as u said, but it still doesnt work.
it work only in case if i will fill all the fields.